# Python - 2D arrays and loops

Tags: python, arrays, loops

I've made a 2D array and loaded in the correct values for the columns. (Age and freq.) When I'm running a loop to find age<10 I get the desired output. But is there a way in which I can print out the corresponding value of freq.?

I'm thinking something like this:

for i in range (0,2Darray): #Oth column, since age is my zeroth column? 
     if i < 10:
          for ii in range(0,2Darray)
           if i < 10
          print i, ii

## Another piece of code I' ve got that might be helpful:

array1 = array([i for i in Age if i<10])

Answer (score 0):

assuming that your 2D array can be accessed like a list of lists:

```
for age,freq in zip(yourArray[0],yourArray[1]):
    if age > 10: print(age,freq)
```

if you give more info on how your array is implemented (`numpy` or something else) i can be more specific

Comment: Thanks :) managed to get it working from this:for Age,freq in (Age_freq):
    if Age < 10:
        print Age,freq